# Create list with N elements of either 0 or 1 adding up to specified number X

Tags: python, list

I'd like to create a list of 0s and/or 1s of length n where the values add up to x.

For example:

```
import random

def foo(x,n):
    list = []
    test = 0
    while test == 0:
        for i in range(n):
            temp = int(random.random()+0.5)
            list.append(temp)
        if sum(list) == x:
            test = 1
            print("here is your list ")
            return list
        list.clear()

print(foo(5, 7))
```

output:
`here is your list [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]`

is there any optimization for my function ?

Comment: Sounds like a pretty straightforward algorithm. What did you try? Also, why is the output `[0,1,1,1,0,1,1]` and not `[1,1,1,1,1,0,0]`?

Comment: Maybe you want to create the list in a specific order, then shuffle it with [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so this is a simple way to do it using random.shuffle.

1. i create a list with the number of [1] wanted.
2. then i added the number of zeros.
3. shuffle the list using random.shuffle function.

   ```
   import random

   def foo(x,n):
       list = []
       list.extend([1]*x)
       list.extend([0]*(n-x))
       random.shuffle(list)
       print(list)

   foo(5, 7)
   ```

and this is the result :
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
('the result changes every time')